# Javascript duplicate array and change values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have data like this :

```
const cards = [
  { name: "angular2" },
  { name: "vue" },
  { name: "react" },
  { name: "grunt" },
  { name: "phantomjs" }
];
```

I want to duplicate and shuffle this array. Also i want to add  `id` property to each item.

```
const duplicateCards = (arr) => {
  const duplicatedArr = [...arr, ...arr];
  for (let i = duplicatedArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    duplicatedArr[i].id = i;
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * i + 1);
    console.log(duplicatedArr[i]);
    [duplicatedArr[i], duplicatedArr[randomIndex]] = [duplicatedArr[randomIndex], duplicatedArr[i]];
  }
  return duplicatedArr;
};
```

The `duplicateCards(cards)` function returns an output like this:

```
[
  { name: 'vue', id: 1 },
  { name: 'angular2', id: 0 },
  { name: 'vue', id: 1 },
  { name: 'grunt', id: 7 },
  { name: 'phantomjs', id: 4 },
  { name: 'phantomjs', id: 4 },
  { name: 'grunt', id: 7 },
  { name: 'react' },
  { name: 'react' },
  { name: 'angular2', id: 0 }
]
```

I tried `concat()` method but I got same result. I want to add a unique id. What is my mistake ? How can I solve this?

Comment: `[...arr, ...arr]` this code doesn't clone your item twice, so you cannot clone like this in this case,

Comment: You forgot to add the line that defines the value of `randomIndex`.

Comment: The expected output should have a unique id per name or for every card?

Comment: @trincot of course I wrote randomIndex in my vscode but forgot to add here :)

Comment: @MajedBadawi yes i want to add to id for every object for example : `{name:"react",id:1}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because although you spread the array with `[...arr, ...arr]`, creating a new array, the object references are still the same, so every object is now referenced twice. This means that any mutation you do (like with assigning to the `id` property) will be visible at two places in the array.

Secondly, you should assign the `id` property before the phase where you start swapping, as you may meet the same object a second time and then assign a different `id` to it, while other objects, which get swapped *to* the index `i`, will *not* get an `id` assigned.

Here is how it could work, by chaining a `.map` on the created array which creates *new* objects:

```js
const duplicateCards = (arr) => {
  const duplicatedArr = [...arr, ...arr].map((o, id) => ({...o, id }));
  for (let i = duplicatedArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * i + 1);
    [duplicatedArr[i], duplicatedArr[randomIndex]] = [duplicatedArr[randomIndex], duplicatedArr[i]];
  }
  return duplicatedArr;
};

const cards = [
  { name: "angular2" },
  { name: "vue" },
  { name: "react" },
  { name: "grunt" },
  { name: "phantomjs" }
];

console.log(duplicateCards(cards));
```